# ASP.NET Add Razor page in Web Application not Web Site, NO MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, razor

I just found a strange thing in Visual Studio 2010.

I can add a Razor page into a Web Site project, but I cannot do it in a Web Application project.

I do know I can create a ASP.NET MVC(1-4) project which allows me to add a Razor page into it.

After I checked the differences between Web Site(WS) project and Web Application(WA) project, it seems to me that WA is to trend to be in most cases and has more features than WS.

So my question is:
Visual Studio 2010 allows us to add a Razor page into a WS project(you can find it when adding a new page in the list of templates), but why it does not provide the Razor page in the template in the WA project?

I'm curious about it. Waiting for your answers :)

Cheers

Comment: Are you looking specifically for the dialog that has all of the shortcuts allowing you to specify the model and all? If so, you need to right-click on the Views folder and select Add => View.

Comment: @Mike, no. I just want to create a Web Application with Razor support but it is not a MVC Web Application.

Comment: as far as I know Razor is only supported with an MVC application because it's a shorthand syntax built to hookup the view and the model.

Comment: @Mike Hi Mike, so if what you said is true, then I am getting more curious about why Razor can be added to a Web Site Project without MVC Framework. Thx

Comment: That's a good question - one I honestly can't answer.

Comment: Did you actually get that Razor page to show up?

Comment: And _"WA is to trend to be in most cases and has more features than WS"_ : re-evaluate that. WA is always nicer for small demos, but for a real project a WS might be more desirable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, why WS might be more desirable for a real project? I thought WA is more powerful? Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when creating a new, Empty web application. I wanted to use MVC. Despite adding the references required, it still won't let me create files by right clicking on a folder.

However, if you have SP1 installed on Visual Studio 2010, you can:

- Right Click > Add > New from Template> Razor MVC View

Hope this helps.